# how to create window child window outside primary window

Tags: winapi, childwindow

I've learned how to create a child window within the parent window, but I want to create a window outside the program's primary window. If I'm not mistaken, a window outside the primary one is still a child window, right? Does it have its own class that needs to be registered? I tried just making another window, but changing the arguments. I got some interesting results, but not a separate window.

Comment: A window can create another window, that is not a child window of the window that creates it. It's also a good idea to show the code that does not work for you, and add a tag to show what language your are using - to help people help you. I would get the book "Programming Windows" by Charles Petzold 5th and/or 6th edition.

Comment: See [window types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#window-types).

Comment: There is an "owner/owned" window relationship which is very much like parent/child but without constraining the owned window's position (a child window position is constrained to be within its parent).

Comment: Read Petzold and then start again